# call php function on clicking link in php

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I had created basic custom module. in that i just filled information form and that information will stored into the database. and that data i am showing into table format. now i want to edit and delete records from clicking links.

I want to call php function on clicking following links

links are:

```
while($data = $result->fetchObject()){
$rows[] = array(

  $data->id,
  $data->name,
  $data->address,
  $data->mob,
  $data->gen,
  $data->email,
  $data->hob,
  l('Edit' .$data->id,'/table', array('query' => array('edi'=>$data-          >id))),  
  l('Delete' .$data->id, '/table', array('query' =>   array('del'=>$data->id))),
);

}
```

and the functions are as follows:

```
function form_values_edit($id){
$id_val = $id;
$my_object = db_select('demo_forms','n')
->fields('n')
->condition('id', $id_val )
->execute()
->fetchAssoc();
return drupal_get_form('demo_form', $my_object);
}

function delete_confirm($form, &$form_state, $id){
$form['delete'] = array(
'#type' => 'value',
'#value' => $id,
);

return confirm_form(
$form,
t('Are you sure you want to delete this?',
'/table',
t('This action cannot be undone'),
t('Delete'),
t('Cancel')
));
}

function delete_confirm_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$record = $form_state['values']['delete'];
if ($record ) {
  $num_deleted = db_delete('demo_forms')
  ->condition('id', $record )
  ->execute();
  drupal_set_message('The record has been deleted!');
}
$form_state['redirect'] = "/table";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a PHP function dynamically by clicking a link, as PHP is a `server side language`. HOWEVER if you load another page, before loading the page you can execute PHP code.

**EDIT**
if you need a PHP function dynamically, what I usually do (and this may be wrong according to some people) is call that function in an `AJAX` call. Note: I would generally use POST for this.

```
$.ajax(
    url: 'url/to/php/function',
    type: 'POST/GET',
    data: {'data' : data},
    success: function(res) {
        // use the result stored in res
    },
    error: function(res) {
        // use res to get the error result
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add check for id field or another unique value in your php code and update or delete rows where id = ... With out unique value you can't do that. Describe your usability and post your html for more...